# python string encoding unicode

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I'm using python 2.7 and I have some problems converting chars like "ä" to "ae".

I'm retrieving the content of a webpage using:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url + str(questionID))
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
data = response.read()
```

After that I'm doing some extraction stuff and there is my problem.

```
extractedStr = pageContent[start:end] // this string contains the "ä" !
extractedStr = extractedStr.decode("utf8") // here I get the error, tried it with encode aswell
extractedStr = extractedStr.replace(u"ä", "ae")
```

--> 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 13: invalid continuation byte

But: my simple trial is working fine...:

```
someStr = "geräusch"
someStr = someStr.decode("utf8")
someStr = someStr.replace(u"ä", "ae")
```

I've got the feeling, it has something to do with WHEN I try to use the .decode() function... I tried it at several positions, no success :(

Comment: use `.decode("latin-1")`

Comment: working fine now, thx.

Comment: No worries, the data is latin-1 encoded, the charset should be in the headers under content-type.

Comment: Be careful to not mix bytes and Unicode. Use only Unicode strings to process text. `someStr.replace(u"ä", "ae")` should be Unicode for both arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Use `.decode("latin-1")` instead. That is what you are trying to decode.